# How to get Javascript cookie to remember DIV state?

Tags: javascript, css, cookies, hide, state

I've got a test site [here](http://unikdesign.net/test) (still in development) and I'm trying to get the little notification at the top to stay hidden once you click close.

Currently my script is like this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.hide {
display:none;
}
.show {
display:block;
}
-->
</style>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var state;
window.onload=function() {
obj=document.getElementById('alert');
state=(state==null)?'show':state;
obj.className=state;

document.getElementById('close').onclick=function() {
obj.className=(obj.className=='show')?'hide':'show';
state=obj.className;
setCookie();
return false;
}
}

function setCookie() {
exp=new Date();
plusMonth=exp.getTime()+(31*24*60*60*1000);
exp.setTime(plusMonth);
document.cookie='State='+state+';expires='+exp.toGMTString();
}

function readCookie() {
if(document.cookie) {
state=document.cookie.split('State=')[1];
}
}
readCookie();
//-->
</script>
```

and then:

```
<div id="alert" class="show" style="float: left; width: 100%;"><div style="width: 80%; text-align:left; float:left;">Sorry for the downtime, we were experiencing some problems with our web host. Everything should be back to normal now =D</div> 
<div style="width: 18%; text-align:right; float:left; padding-right: 20px;"><a href='#' id="close">close</a></div> </div>
```

but it doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Sam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to fix readCookie, your call to split will return everything after "State=", which will be stored in the first offset of the returned array, so instead do this:

```
function readCookie() {
    if(document.cookie) {
        var tmp = document.cookie.split(';')[0];
        state = tmp.split('=')[1];
        alert(state);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah, sorry - thought Mr Mage answered first. Fixed =)

Comment: @sm - which of the two answers solved your problem? You should 'tick' the one that was most helpful. If they were all helpful you should vote them all up as a courtesy - standard SO etiquette.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - I don't have enough reputation (yet...)

Answer (score 1):

For me, it does work (Firefox 3.5, Windows XP). But the div will not disappear before the site has finished loading. You might want to set the div to `style="hide"` in the first place and have it appear after the page has loaded.