# css javascript cookie to remember div toggle state

Tags: javascript, cookies

I am fairly new to javascript and seem to be having trouble with cookies. I have found a lot of posts with similar questions but as I start reading the answers I get more and more confused. I have even tried to follow along with youtube tuorials but can't seem to find someone who explains it properly. I have been stuck on this for the last 3 hours and I cannot give up now.

I have a div which can be toggled to be either visible or not. I am using a javascript function for this.

```
function exp_col(x, y){
 x = document.getElementById(x);
 y = document.getElementById(y);

if (x.style.display == "block") {
    x.style.display = "none";
    y.src = "images/layout/plus.png";
} else {
    x.style.display = "block";
    y.src = "images/layout/minus.png";
}}
```

When a user toggles a div, I want to be able to remember that and keep the state of the div the same even if they go on to a different page. I've been told I need cookies for this but I can't seem to make one that works. I'm not sure if I even understand them properly. I know they store information in pairs like name-value but I don't understand how to use this to do what I want. Where do I set the cookie? How do I set it? How do I use it to do what I want? I'm just really confused at the moment and would appreciate some help.

Live example of toggle @ http://hello-world.cu.cc

Thanks

Comment: ESET shows me `The web page is on the list of websites with potentially dangerous content.`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get Javascript cookie to remember DIV state?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1283949/how-to-get-javascript-cookie-to-remember-div-state)

Comment: @Mr.Alien I can assure you it is a safe website since it was created from scratch by me. It's most likely due to the domain extension .cu.cc because they are free and therefore sometimes assumed as being spammy/harmful websites(I think..) Anyway, sorry about that and feel free to just ignore this question.

Comment: I would use localStorage if older browsers are not an issue. http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html

Comment: @rlemon That is one of the posts I have already read but could not make any sense of. For one it uses classes to change the state but I need my classes to stay the same for my other styles to apply to them. Also I don't understand it enough to be able to modify it for my own needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is rought example of what you probably need

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.cookie.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var toggle=$('.toggle');
            var inner=toggle.find('.inner');
            if($.cookie('divState')=='visible')
                inner.show();
            else
                inner.hide();
            toggle.find('a').click(function(){
                if(inner.is(':visible'))
                    $.cookie('divState', 'hidden');
                else
                    $.cookie('divState', 'visible');
                inner.toggle();
            });
        });
    </script>
    <style type="text/css">
        div
        {
            padding: 2px;
            border: 1px solid #ccc; width: 300px
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="toggle">
        <a>Click me</a>
        <div class="inner">
            Some text <br />
            Some text <br />
            Some text <br />
            Some text <br />
            Some text <br />
            Some text <br />

        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

click on "click me" and upadte the page several times - you will se that div state is remembered. it is stored in cookies.

I used jquery if don't mind. 
What I tried to show is just workflow. If you can't use jquery it's pretty easy to convert example into native javascript.

live demo - http://jsfiddle.net/CQFJ4/

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for. I haven't started learning jQuery yet so I won't be using this because I don't understand it fully plus the code for the cookie look mighty confusing but thanks for posting this anyway. I can maybe use it as a starting point and try to reverse engineer the code (if that makes sense)

Answer (score 0):

Setting a cookie is straightforward:

```
document.cookie="mydiv=block";
```

And you can go here for examples on reading and erasing cookies:  http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html